# Can't trigger this controller action in a view (it isn't a default Rails RESTful action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller called **votes_controller.rb**. In that file there is the following action:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    vote_attr = params[:vote].merge :user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1
    @vote = @post.votes.create(vote_attr)    
  end
```

(etc...)

I want to trigger the `vote_up` action in a view:

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**:

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", ??? %>
```

Here is the whole file just in case:

```
<h2>posts show</h2>

<span>Title: <%= @post.title %></span><br />
<span>Content: <%= @post.content %></span><br />
<span>User: <%= @post.user.username %></span><br />

<%= link_to "Vote Up", ??? %>

<h2>Comments</h2>

<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Commenter</b>
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

I have no idea what to type in the ??? part (I would also like to make it work as `:remote`. My intention is to trigger the action without refreshing the page).

Do I have to add something in the `routes.rb`?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a route in `routes.rb`. Use a named route to be easy to use in the view. Something like:

```
get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', as: 'vote_up'
```

And so can now use in the view

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post) %>
```

and in the controller

```
def vote_up
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

See [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Why did you use `get` instead of `map`?

Comment: you mean instead of `match` ? `get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up'` is a shorthand version of `match 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', :via => :get`. This url is only called via `GET` in your example, so I declared only the `GET`route.